# how to get three level subquery using postgress?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

So I have three entity Plans, milestones and actions.

Plans hasMany milestones.
Milestones hasMany actions.

what will be correct way of representing them ?

Plan (id, title)
milestones (id, title, planId)
actions (id, title, milestoneId)

Or should PlanMilestones and MilestoneActions through table should be introduced ?

Not all milestone will have actions.

```
   var plans = plans = [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'plan title',
            milestones: [{
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'milestone two',
                    planId: 1,  
                    actions: [{
                            id: 3,
                            title: 'action title title',
                            milestoneId: 2
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            title: 'action title four',
                            milestoneId: 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {

                id: 3,
                title: 'milestone three',
                planId: 1,
                actions: [{
                        id: 6,
                        title: 'action title six',
                        milestoneId: 3

                    },
                    {
                        id: 7,
                        title: 'action title seven',
                        milestoneId: 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'plan title two',
        milestones: [{
                id: 8,
                planId: 2,
                title: 'milestone eight',
                actions: [{
                        id: 12,
                        title: 'action title twelve',
                        milestoneId: 8
                    },
                    {
                        id: 14,
                        title: 'action title fourteen',
                        milestoneId: 8
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 20,
                planId: 2,
                title: 'milestone twenty',
                actions: [{
                        id: 16,
                        title: 'action title sixteen',
                        milestoneId: 20
                    },
                    {
                        id: 17,
                        title: 'action title seventeen',
                        milestoneId: 20
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    {
      plan: 3,
      title: 'plan three'

   }
]
```

I need to get above json from three tables, plans, milestones and actions. The relationship between them is plans has many milestones and actions. Milestones hasMany actions.

Plans(id, title)
Milestones(id, title, planId)
Actions(id, title, milestonesId, planId)

```
SELECT
json_build_object('id', m.id, 'title', m.title, 'actions', (
SELECT
json_agg(row_to_json(t))
FROM (
SELECT
id, title, milestoneid FROM action
WHERE
milestoneid = m.id) t)) AS milestone
FROM
milestone m;
```

What I have written is above which gives the json from the milestone but im not able to write the query along with plans.

Answer (score 1):

[Click: step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c06131258c1b7d85b8bf4a6a16c7479)

```
SELECT
    json_agg(plan) as plans                                               -- 7
FROM (
    SELECT 
        json_build_object('id', p_id, 'milestones',                       -- 6
            json_agg(milestone)                                           -- 5
        ) as plan
    FROM (    
        SELECT
            p.id as p_id,
            json_build_object('id', m.id, 'plan_id', p.id, 'actions',     -- 4
                json_agg(                                                 -- 3
                    json_build_object('id', a.id, 'milestone_id', m.id)   -- 2
                )
            ) as milestone
        FROM actions a
        JOIN milestones m ON a.id = m.id_action                           -- 1
        JOIN plans p ON m.id = p.id_milestone 
        GROUP BY p.id, m.id                                               -- 3
    ) s
    GROUP BY p_id                                                         -- 5
) s
```

1. Join all tables together
2. Create `action` object
3. Group all `action` objects per `milestone` and aggregate them into a new JSON array
4. Create `milestone` object
5. Group all `milestone` objects per `plan` and aggregate them into a new JSON array
6. Create `plan` object
7. Group all `plan` objects and aggregate them into a new JSON array

---

If it is not absolutely necessary, I would recommend not to store parent ids in their children. This is redundant data storage. You know the ids automatically when you traverse the JSON's tree structure.

Comment: The relationship you created to demonstrate the sql is different than the database design I have, is there a way I can talk to you regarding best practice to design  table for above data. @S-Man

Comment: You can add the DDL for your tables and some sample data to your question to clarify it. Furthermore you could use a fiddle as I did with my demo.

Comment: I have updated my question. As you mentioned its bad practice to add parentId to child table. Please can you suggest relation for the above table, according to your example there will be lots of null value if the parent has the child fk.

Comment: Ok, your referencing the other way round. So the algorithm stays the same, you only need to join slightly different at the beginning: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8dd84b9684d9dc3c38bd0bfc1b25fffb; Nevertheless, maybe it could be better to create mapping tables instead of referencing in the data tables (instead of column id_milestone a table plan_milestone and milestone_action might be better: plan join planmilestone join milestone join milestoneaction join action). But aside from the different join the algorithm stays the same in all cases

Comment: thank you but my problem is that it does not list all the plans but list only plan that has milestone as well as action.

Comment: All these points are not described in the question. Because it takes a lot of time to create good answers. So, before going any further, please add some sample table data and the expected output to the question, so we could see the expected result.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but the thing I was looking for is listing all the plans along with milestone and actions if they exists but it should display all the plans because of this I cannot accept the answer even though I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok, you need LEFT JOINs. These keep the original values even if there is no value to join with. But then you are creating some NULL elements, that would be inserted into the json_build_objects JSONs. So after LEFT-Joining you have to filter. Variant a) Create empty arrays instead: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ed199213f261538bb68ee8https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=63c924fcfb86598728003a3711eaa362f54302a676 Variant b) Don't add milestones/actions child if none exist: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=63c924fcfb86598728003a3711eaa362